# Normalize Sparse Matrix along rows in C++ Eigen

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, eigen

I wrote a function to normalize sparse matrix along rows using C++ Eigen; however, I feel that it can be improved, and that I am not using some built in functions of Eigen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace Eigen;

std::vector<double> get_weights(SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> sm);
SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> row_normalize(SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> sm);

int main()
{
  MatrixXd silly(6, 3);

  silly << 0, 1, 36,
           0, 3, 0,
           0, 0, 0,
           3, 2, 1,
           0, 1, 0,
           2, 0, 9;

  SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> sparse_silly = silly.sparseView();

  SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> normalized = row_normalize(sparse_silly);
  std::cout << "normalized" << std::endl;
  std::cout << normalized << std::endl;

  SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> test = normalized * normalized.transpose();
  // Checking that all diagonal elements of non-zero rows are 1
  std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
  std::cout << test << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> row_normalize(SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> sm)
 {
   std::vector<double> weights = get_weights(sm);
   SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> sm_weights(sm.rows(), sm.rows());
   for(int i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i)
     {
       sm_weights.insert(i,i) = weights[i];
     }

   return sm_weights * sm;
 }  

std::vector<double> get_weights(SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> sm)
{
  std::vector<double> weights;
  for (int i = 0; i < sm.rows(); ++i)
    {
      double my_sum = 0;
      double *val_ptr = sm.row(i).valuePtr();

      if(sm.row(i).nonZeros())
        // avoid division by zero problem
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < sm.row(i).nonZeros(); ++j) 
            {
              my_sum += (*val_ptr * (*val_ptr));
              val_ptr++;
            }
          weights.push_back(1.0 / sqrt(my_sum));
        }
      else
        {
          weights.push_back(0);
        }
    }
  return weights;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I'd put the `Eigen` headers below the STL headers.  Also, `<math.h>` should be `<cmath>`, the latter being the C++ library incorporated into the `std` namespace.
- You can define `main()` below the other functions, allowing you to save a bit of room by eliminating the function prototypes.
- You don't need that flushing with `std::endl`.  To get just a newline, output a `"\n"`.
- `main()` doesn't need an explicit `return 0`.  As reaching this point implies success, the compiler will do this return for you.
- You shouldn't use an `int` here:

  > ```
  > for(int i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i)
  >   {
  >     sm_weights.insert(i,i) = weights[i];
  >   }
  > ```

  If you had your compiler warnings up high (and they should be), you should've been told about a type-mismatch here.  The type for `i` should instead be `std::size_type` (an unsigned type), which is the return type of `size()` for each STL container class.
- For this `for` loop:

  > ```
  > for (int j = 0; j < sm.row(i).nonZeros(); ++j) 
  >   {
  >     my_sum += (*val_ptr * (*val_ptr));
  >     val_ptr++;
  >   }
  > ```

  `val_ptr++` can still be put into the loop statement:

  ```
  for (int j = 0; j < sm.row(i).nonZeros(); ++j, val_ptr++) 
  {
      my_sum += (*val_ptr * (*val_ptr));
  }
  ```

  I'm also unsure about all the raw pointer use here.  Raw pointers in C++ should be kept to a minimum, so there may be a way to do this without using any of them.
- You pass `sm` by value in both of your functions, however, it doesn't look like you're trying to allow the compiler to perform move semantics.  But you're also using the argument in such a way that it's *only* being read for writing to other values.  In such a case, you should pass `sm` by `const&`.